# Eclipse plugin for creating Class/sequence diagram?

Tags: java, eclipse, class-design, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I am using objectAid eclipse plugin to create class/sequence diagram. Its good when you have all code in place and just
generate the class/sequence diagram out of it. But its not good when i have to do some modifications like

1)Create some class in diagram when code does not exist

2)Remove/add some method/association in diagram

Is there any open source plugin that allows to add/modification in  diagram created from code?

Comment: You can try Astah but it will give you this feature when you will have license for the same.

Comment: Yes, it is paid one!

Comment: I am looking for opensource

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but be sure to [provide enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: @SauravKumarMehta Is there any eclipse plugin for the the astah ?